# Could NOT find LLVM (missing: LLVM_DIR)

Tags: fedora, source, llvm

I'm trying to install darktable from source on Fedora 27. I've installed [all dependencies](https://redmine.darktable.org/projects/darktable/wiki/Building_darktable_22#Fedora-24-and-25), but when I run cmake I got error:

```
-- Could NOT find LLVM (missing: LLVM_DIR)
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:381 (message):
  Could not find LLVM 3.9+
```

What should be the content of this variable.

I've tried this:

```
$ whereis llvm
llvm: /usr/lib64/llvm
$ export LLVM_DIR=/usr/lib64/llvm
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/darktable/ ..
```

but got the same error that it can't find llvm. I have llvm version 5.0.2

Comment: Try `cmake -DLLVM_DIR=/usr/lib64/llvm ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same while trying to build darktable *release-2.7.0* on fedora 29.

Was able to resolve it by installing *llvm-devel*

```bsh
dnf install llvm-devel
```